# R session aborted error when using beep function

Tags: r

I am using a beep function with conditional statement in for loop but as soon as the beep plays, I get the error "R session aborted". Any solution to tackle this error?

```
   for(i in 1:(nrow(accdata)-1)){
   row1 <- accdata[i,]
   for(j in (i+1):nrow(accdata)){
   row2 <- accdata[j,]
   if(abs(row1$Frame - row2$Frame) <= maxFrameDiff &&
   abs(row1$midx - row2$midx) <= maxDist &&
   abs(row1$midy - row2$midy) <= maxDist &&
    row1$Object != row2$Object){ # object must be different
      dupes <- c(dupes,i,j)
     beep()

   }
```

This is the code I am using

Comment: If you want to be a C programmer you should actually use C. This is not how you do this in R. Anyway, does the session still crash if you insert `Sys.sleep(1)` after `beep`? From which package is the `beep` function?

Comment: Yes it is still crashing after using Sys.sleep(1). beep is from beepr package

Comment: Well, can you `beep` successfully outside of the loop?

Comment: Well, the thing I am trying to do demands beep function inside for loop.

Comment: Yes, but does it work outside the loop? That is pertinent to identifying the issue.

Comment: Got the solution using Sys.sleep function. Thanks mate. God Bless

Answer (score 0):

Answer goes to Roland. You can use `Sys.sleep`to introduce a delay and to prevent the overflow of `beep` messages and subsiquent R crash. Please see the code below:

```
library(beepr)

# data.frame simulation
accdata <- data.frame(
  Frame = rnorm(3), 
  midx = rnorm(3),
  midy = rnorm(3),
  Object = rnorm(3))

maxFrameDiff <- 100
maxDist <- 100

dupes <- numeric(100)

# cycle with beeps
for (i in 1:(nrow(accdata) - 1)){
  row1 <- accdata[i, ]

  for(j in (i + 1):nrow(accdata)){
    row2 <- accdata[j, ]
    if (abs(row1$Frame - row2$Frame) <= maxFrameDiff &&
       abs(row1$midx - row2$midx) <= maxDist &&
       abs(row1$midy - row2$midy) <= maxDist &&
       row1$Object != row2$Object) { # object must be different
        dupes <- c(dupes,i,j)
        beep()
        Sys.sleep(1)
    }
  }
}
```